# Как исправить ошибку при миграции БД на Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить такую ошибку?

```
max-PC% heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on maxprof-cinema... up, run.8028
== 20160428140718 ChangeDateFieldTypeBack: migrating      ==========================
-- change_column(:film_sessions, :date, :date)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations     canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "date" cannot be cast automatically to type date
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING date::date".
ALTER TABLE "film_sessions" ALTER COLUMN "date" TYPE date
```

Не понимаю где это прописать: `USING date::date`

**Падающая миграция:**

```
class ChangeDateFieldTypeBack < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column(:film_sessions, :date, :date)
  end
end
```

Comment: Добавил код миграции) Понятия не имею почему локально все отлично, а на сервере начинаются проблемы.. Подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: Это не та миграция.

Comment: Точно, обновил вопрос

Comment: Локально у вас какая БД используется?

Comment: sqlite3 - стандартная

Comment: А, ха-ха. Вот вам урок. Зеркалируйте среду продакшена :)

Comment: До этого заливал тестовые проекты добавляя два гема в production group и все работало) 
"Зеркалируйте среду продакшена" - немного подробнее пожалуйста))

Comment: Если у вас постгрес на сервере, поднимайте постгрес у себя. Так проблемы обычно всплывают раньше и проверить решение проще.

Comment: Хорошо, вполне логично) Но в данный момент как можно решить такую проблему?

Comment: Кхм, а сейчас она какого типа?

Comment: Кто она?) 
Если база данных, то локальную пока не менял. Но логика подсказывает, что если поменяю БД локально, то ошибка будет та же, и сайт перестанет работать и локально)

Comment: Колонка, очевидно. Вы хоть текст ошибки-то перевели? :)

Comment: Добавил миграцию, где меняю тип поля date на string. Думал, что может помочь. Но ошибка на сервере та же

Comment: Конечно перевел)

Comment: Естественно, та миграция ж осталась и пытается выполниться, чинить надо её. С какого типа на какой меняется колонка?

Comment: Ага, в миграции которая не выполняется колонка меняется с типа string на date

Comment: Можно удалить столбец, и добавить с тем же именем и другим типом.

Comment: для начала поменяйте в development БД на туже что и в production. и воспроизведите ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [**МакандраКарточкам**](http://makandracards.com/makandra/18691-postgresql-vs-rails-migration-how-to-change-columns-from-string-to-integer), во-он туда:

```
change_column :film_sessions, :date, 'date USING "date"::date'
#   это на всякий случай, date же является типом ^    ^
```

...это наглая эксплуатация особенностей синтаксиса SQL, да ещё и конкретного диалекта, а потому не стоит ожидать, что это заработает где-либо кроме PostgreSQL (даже в SQLite!).

А если SQLite такое позволил сделать неявно, это камень в огород SQLite, поскольку **конверсия из строки в дату в общем случае теряет данные**.